# Register both generic and specific implementation of an interface with ASP.NET Core DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-mvc

I've read the Armen Shimoon's article [ASP.NET Core: Factory Pattern Dependency Injection](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/05/09/asp-net-core-factory-pattern-dependency-injection/) and I've decided to solve my ASP.NET Core DI problem using the technique suggested by him.
I’ve got a generic interface:

```
public interface IItemRepository<out T> where T : BaseItem
```

and its generic implementation:

```
public class ItemRepository<T> : IItemRepository<T> where T : BaseItem
```

I register it with:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IItemRepository<>), typeof(ItemRepository<>));
```

But for **Currency** I’ve got a specific implementation:

```
public class CurrencyRepository : ItemRepository<Currency>
```

(Curency is of the **BaseItem** type.) What I want is to register

```
CurrencyRepository
```

for

```
IItemRepository<Currency>
```

and

```
ItemRepository<T>
```

for all other items that implement **BaseItem**. I created a factory class to accomplish this:

```
public class ItemRepositoryFactory : IServiceFactory> where T : BaseItem
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ItemRepositoryFactory(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ItemRepository Build()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Currency))
            return new CurrencyRepository(_context) as ItemRepository;

        return new ItemRepository(_context);
    }
}
```

but I don’t know how to register it with **IServiceCollection**. Or maybe I’m not on the right way at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can't register it explicitly. ASP.NET Core DI is meant to be simple and offer out of box DI/IoC experience and easy for other DI/IoC containers to plugin.

So the built-in IoC doesn't offer Auto-Registrations, Assembly scanning, Decorators or registration of all interfaces/sub types of the class.

For concrete implementations, there is a "workaround"

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService,MyService>();
services.AddScoped<MyService>(provider => provider.GetService<IMyService>());
```

Then both `MyService` and `IMyService` inside a constructor would receive the same instance of the class.

But this doesn't work with open generics and is a manuell process. For automatic discovery or registration you need a 3rd party IoC container, such as Autofac, StructureMap etc.

But in your concrete sample it should be enough to register `IItemRepository<Currency>` inside your `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddScoped<IItemRepository<Currency>,CurrencyRepository>();
```

But actually the open generic should cover this case already, if you inject `IItemRepository<Currency>` into your services.